# TYPO3 Flux template with WAMP issue

Tags: wamp, typo3, flux

I have install wamp server in Windows base pc.And also increased of the Apache's stack size.

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
  ThreadStackSize 8388608
</IfModule>
```

My TYPO3 installation version 6.2.4 with Flux 7.0, I can access backend as well extension manager and extension builder, Problem is that frontend of site takes too much time to loading

Your help is very appreciated.

Comment: There are hundreds of pages out there on typo3 speed issues and also many on how to speed it up. Seems like it is just a slow beasty. Do you have enough machine to run it in?

Comment: Yes, I have. I faced this only when I used TYPO3 with Flux template method. TYPO3 with templavoila and Fluid method works fine :(

Comment: Well it seems that Flux may be your problem